Can't write to /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages using systemd service
What:  The systemd service I wrote does not allocate huge pages as expected.
Why: Huge pages are needed by our hardware service, and the huge pages must be allocated on NUMA node 0.
How I’ve written a systemd service file that should set the values correctly. However, it doesn’t. When I run the commands interactive as root, it works fine. There is no error message displayed.
I've having trouble setting up a one-shot systemd service that allocates huge pages among the two NUMA nodes.  If I execute the commands at the command line, it works. If it gets executed through systemd, nothing happens.  I can see that the commands are getting executed in /var/log/messages, but they are having no effect.
Here is /var/log/messages:
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 systemd[1]: Starting Huge Pages Reservation...
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 echo[27493]: 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 echo[27494]: 71 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 cat[27495]: 1
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 cat[27496]: 64
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 id[27497]: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 systemd[1]: pacbio-huge-pages.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 15 00:01:07 dev05 systemd[1]: Finished Huge Pages Reservation.

Here is the service:
[Unit]
Description=Huge Pages Reservation
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=dev-hugepages.mount
ConditionPathExists=/sys/devices/system/node
ConditionKernelCommandLine=hugepagesz=1GB

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/echo 0  > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
ExecStart=/bin/echo 71 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
ExecStart=cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
ExecStart=cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
ExecStart=/usr/bin/id

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target

If I execute those echo commands under su, it works correctly. All of these commands were executed with a few seconds of each other, so this is not a boot race condition.
At the command line, I do it like this, and it works.
$ echo 71 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
71
$ cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
71
$ echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
0
$ cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
0


It seems that the echo command takes the whole params "0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages" as a string to print. Put it this way "ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >  /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages"

@junka Thanks, that is the problem.  Btw, if you want to copy/paste my answer, I will delete mine and approve yours so you get credit.

The documentation for ExecStart specifically says:

Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

@junka left a comment explaining the correct solution: Run the command specifically inside a bash shell so that the redirection works.
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages

